# Would forgetting something make it inaccessible to psychokinetic hackers?

Tags: internal-consistency, security

So my organization in my planet needs a way to dispose of information such that it cannot be retrieved by people with PK. The PK people generally can enter a person's mind, read their mind, access what their victims can remember, and can snap their bones, melt their brain, squeeze their sensitive body parts, or simply stimulate their nerves. They can also make their victims see whatever they want.

The method that I think would counter this to protect sensitive knowledge would be to make the people who have sensitive info (like nuclear codes, passwords, locations of keys, addresses, names, etc.) forget the information. Since the information is not known to the victim, any examination of their mind by the psychics, and any physical torture or psychological torture wouldn't compromise the information, because the victim would have no information to give other than false information.

Is this consistent, given all of the above?

Please assume that the victim has truly forgotten the information, and has no traces of the memory in their mind.

Comment: If "the victim... has no traces of the memory in their mind" then I don't see how the answer could be anything but "yes".

Comment: @Cadence I'm new to worldbuilding, and since we are talking about PK I was unsure if my logic or reasoning was consistent. I want to make sure I have the rules of my world right

Comment: Psychokinesis is not a real-world phenomenon, so it can do whatever you want it to.  If you want it able to recover "deleted" information then it can, if you don't want it to work that way then it won't.  I suggest you think about what the limits are on this power - everyone has to know their own password, someone has to know the nuclear codes if such things exist, so how can people protect themselves from the power?  Limited to line of sight, or touch, or nowhere near an oscillating EM field or what?

Comment: +1 just for posting a better-than-average [tag:internal-consistency] question with your very first post. Welcome to [worldbuilding.se], Kaley, and cheers!

Comment: Psychokinetic doesn't mean anything like you think that it does, it means manipulation and control of physical things with the mind, it's another word for telekinesis and has nothing to do with telepathy .. learn the meaning of words to avoid looking silly .. @KerrAvon2055 not entirely true, an existing word with an existing definition of its meaning in fantasy and elsewhere is not subject to 'complete' freedom, you may have some freedom to tweek the exact mechanics of how it works but you can't use it to mean something totally different without looking a bit ignorant and foolish.

Comment: Y has x and I want x from Y.  But now Y does not have x.   I cannot get x from Y.   Yes, that holds true.  I might still squeeze sensitive body parts.  In a fit of pique, you know.

Comment: What use is extremely important information if it can't be remembered? Then it needs to be written down first, and we have less talented people to steal that kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

**Not consistent**

To the best of my knowledge, the only way a person's memory can be erased is with physical damage to the brain.

"Forgetting" something doesn't mean the knowledge and/or association is gone. All it means is the brain's ability to trivially bring it into conscious thought has lapsed. A great many memories can be retrieved with simple techniques like sound, odor, or "jogging the memory" with hints and clues about what the memory was about. Many more memories can be had through hypnosis and people can improve their capacity to remember through training techniques that strengthen the brain's habit of recall.

Memory can be blocked through trauma. The memory is still there, but an association (usually with pain or fear) has been created in the brain that makes it very difficult to retrieve the memory. But even these are often retrievable.

So, no, your solution is not consistent. The fact that someone can't remember something doesn't mean the memory isn't there to be stolen.

**But, if the information really was erased, would that work?**

Here I get to invoke my favorite Worldbuilding quote: "Can you launch an ICBM horizontally?" "Sure! Why would you want to?" (The Hunt for Red October) Of course deleting the data would keep it from being stolen. There's no data to steal. But what would be the point? It's not there for the individual to use, either. Bummer for POTUS if those nuclear codes are ever needed.

**What are common SciFi tropes?**

- An individual is trained to block memories from theft.
- A block is created such that memories cannot be accessed willingly by the thief or the individual. (My favorite was the encrypted solution adopted in the movie "Johnny Mnemonic.")
- An individual is trained to actively fight telepathic invasion.

**OK, but could something else not a trope work?**

Yes. A quote attributed to British Prime Minister Benjamin Disraeli comes to mind, "the difference between an idiot and a genius is a pencil and a piece of paper." Don't memorize the data. Have someone else write it down and put the paper in your pocket. A traditional pickpocket might get it, but your PK assault team will come up with bupkis.

Comment: Ok, I will try to use something like the piece of paper. Maybe the person's phone could work? So the hardware not the software could be identified and used as Auth, or maybe a good old old fashioned key would work. Is that what you are saying? Use an actual thing (paper, key, access card, mobile phone, special material) as the authentication, so it can only be stolen, not psychically breached?

Comment: That's basically it. The strongest defense against telepathy is to not store the target information in anyone's head. Off the top of my head (hah), the biggest problem with telepathy would be identity theft because certain kinds of information (like your birthday) are simply part of your childhood. But there are also other alternatives, you can make telepathy difficult such that constantly humming a tune would keep thieves at bay. Suddenly telepathic theft (like most theft) becomes one of opportunity or skill and not convenience.

Comment: Maybe nit picking, but not all memories are retained. The neurons most involved with memory undergo periodic synaptic pruning (that's why few people have real memories from when they were 2, 3, or even 4) and do die. They are replaced, but whether the memory involved is kept is a coin toss. It's normal, not brain damage, although brain damage can also cause memory loss.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Can you cite studies to support that?

Comment: @JBH - Absolutely, but commenters are not required to support their comments with studies. It's easy enough to google [synaptic pruning](https://www.healthline.com/health/synaptic-pruning) and memory. If you want to know more, you can ask on Biology, Psychology and Cognition, or Medical Sciences. I hope that T**Y**L.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Commenters are expected to act with civility when asked for extra information. The first sentence of your linked article states, "Synaptic pruning is a natural process that occurs in the brain between early childhood and adulthood" and the pruning appears to only continue [into our 20s](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20803-brains-synaptic-pruning-continues-into-your-20s/). The OP is asking about robbing adults. I don't believe your nitpick rationally falsifies any aspect of my answer to the OPs question.

Comment: @JBH - Please elaborate on where I was uncivil. Synaptic pruning continues throughout life, actually, but is accelerated during particular time periods, with early childhood and late adolescence being periods of tremendous activity. Also, as I stated, neurons involved with memory die, and their replacements may or may not preserve a memory. You are simply wrong. I'm not. As I said, if you want to know more, there are sites where this kind of question fits perfectly within their domain. (Nota Bene: the article which I linked is written for laypeople. It's not comprehensive.)

Comment: I can nitpick some more if you like. Hypnosis is notoriously bad at memory retrieval, and (for a variety of reasons) is not credible, producing a surfeit of *false memories*. (Also supportable.) Without any help, we produce a lot of false memories on our own. Memory is an interesting thing. One thing you were right about, though, is the power of olfactory input to bring up long unthought-of memories.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I've not yet found evidence that synaptic pruning occurs throughout life. In fact, the link I provided called the discovery of it happening into the 20's, "surprising." You are simply wrong - unless you can cite proof of either your claims or your elevation to godhood. I don't know you and your participation on this stack has been distant and limited. If you don't think my answer is valuable to the OP, down vote it. If you think you have a better perspective, answer the question (an action that benefits everyone). But if you're trying to make my answer better, provide citations.

Comment: The link you provided was also written for laypeople and not comprehensive. Don't believe everything you read on the internet. My participation on this stack has no bearing on my reliability. I'm not a god, and if anyone is being uncivil, it's you. I think my background makes me a more reliable source of medical information than you, and again, I'm not wrong. Comments are provided to improve an answer, but also to point out errors.

Comment: @JBH Don't mean to be a killjoy, but if someone was aware that there was a paper in their pocket, or any other physical object containing secret info, couldn't a PK with the abilities described be able to detect that? They would read their mind and know exactly where on their person the object is hidden, defeating the purpose.

Comment: @TheresaKay Detect the fact that the paper was in their pocket? Sure! But the paper must still be obtained and the odds are the PK knew the person holding the paper had the secret, so nothing particularly new was learned. The idea was presented only to demonstrate an alternative to the OP's conundrum that didn't rely on already well-used tropes.

Comment: @JBH I hear the logic. Still think it would be better if a PK couldn't find the location of the info. Remember - if they could stimulate nerves, snap bones, etc. then they could easily obtain the paper once they know its location. But it's definitely a better solution than the overused trained-to-protect-against-telepathy scheme.

Comment: @TheresaKay You're correct, but those kinds of details are up to the OP.

Comment: "constantly humming a tune would keep thieves at bay" -- this exact tactic is used in the novel _The Demolished Man_, by Alfred Bester. Telepathy is a major element of the story, and is discussed in far more detail than seen in most fiction.

Comment: [Microglia regulation of synaptic plasticity and learning and memory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8530121/) Read and learn something factual for a change.

Answer (score 0):

Rather internally consistent to me, however:

1. human brain is messy and does record information like computer but in pieces / multiple places so some shreds can be overlooked while erasing
2. You may remove information but missed information based on it.
   For example person does not remember existence of top secret aircraft research project, but inexplicably considers existing aircraft fleet as clearly outdated because of huge radar cross section and high IR emission. No idea which features had the experimental aircraft...

By occasion - if you can mold someones memory than better fill it with harmless for subject disinfo. If some shreds of the original info can remain then fill it with a few versions to create a total mess for any interrogator.

Answer (score 0):

As JBH mentioned, you could ensure information is not known to the victim by... not telling the potential victim anything.  If you need to move information, go for the modern conventional method of locking it up and hiring a courier to move it for you.  On the other hand, if you're worried about the originator of the information (or other people who must know it) being captured, take advice from Alfred Hitchcock:

> Good evening. I hope you'll excuse me if I appear a trifle excited but I've just come into possession of a <s>cure for insomnia</s> way to dispose of information. It comes in capsule form.  For best results, they must be taken internally. Here is the handy applicator.  It is an amazingly simple device. An idiot can operate it and indeed many do. These objects play an important part in tonight's tale. It is called <s>"A Bullet for Baldwin."</s> "Psychokinetic Antivirus."

This would be similar to how you prevent hackers from accessing information on a computer.  You can probably safeguard information effectively by airgapping the system (your knower lives in a bunker), but if a PK hacker gains access to them, wipe the hard drive!